# This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running

Tags: windows, docker, containers, docker-engine, docker-daemon

I am new to Docker and after writing docker version in cmd

I got this error:

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Edit:** the OS is Windows.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You have to start the docker Engine on your machine as the error indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Linux** you should check the daemon status by `systemctl status docker.service`, then:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable docker.socket

sudo systemctl start docker.socket
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

On Windows you should check its status by the **Windows Service Manager**.

Comment: Your instructions are for Linux systems, the OP is using Windows.

Comment: The post owner did not specified the OS. In that case you should check the service status by the Windows Service Manager.

Comment: They stated _"in cmd"_, and the Docker socket path also indicates it's Windows.

Comment: I edit the post to make it more clear.